# Use 100% div width, if 50% width is too small

Tags: html, css

How could one go about creating a `div`, that would have a default size of `XX%`, however, if the screen gets too small it would switch into `100%` size? I have tried using `min-width` property but the problem with this is that it will not be responsive after the `min-width` is reached and will overflow if the screen is even smaller.

Comment: media-queries, probably.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use `@media` queries. So let's say you have a `<div>` that should take up only 50% of the web page and then you need to show it full width once it enters mobile phone, say `640px` width:

```css
div {
  width: 50%;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 640px) {
  div {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with `@media` *queries*, e.g.:

```css
div {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid;
}

@media (max-width: 568px) { /* adjust to your needs */
  div {width: 100%}
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you must use `@media` for that like this :

```
@media screen and (min-width: 769px) {
    /* STYLES HERE */
}

@media screen and (min-device-width: 481px) and (max-device-width: 768px) { 
    /* STYLES HERE */
}

@media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {
    /* STYLES HERE */
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much for answering, really helped me out!